# Memcached Persistence on Tapestry5

Tags: servlets, memcached, tapestry

I've searched endlessly and am unable to find a way to implement Memcached on Tapestry5 such that I instantiate only 1 "MemcachedClient" object for the entire application.

I have a page whose responses need to be cached.
I want to create only 1 instance of a "MemcachedClient" on this server (regardless of session) and query the cache using the same object instance.

I've tried @SessionState but this does not help, since my "user" is a load generator and hence each request results in a new object instance.

Any advice please?

Edit: The same goes for any other variable that I want to persist across visits, regardless of session. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [define a service in tapestry-ioc](http://tapestry.apache.org/defining-tapestry-ioc-services.html) (services are singletons by default)

This will be done in your IOC module either with a builder method or via ServiceBinder.bind(...)